# Subsetting a variable by pattern

Tags: awk, wildcards

I have a delimited file with the following format that I have assigned to a bash variable "foo":

```
echo $foo

A  1  hello
B  2  hello
C  3  hello
D  4  world
E  5  world
F  6  world
```

I am trying to find a preferably awk-based solution that can split this variable into new text files such that all of the rows with identical values in column #3 are in one file. In a perfect world, the files would be named after the string in column #3 In this case, the files would be "hello.txt and "world.txt" with the following contents:

```
cat hello.txt
A  1  hello
B  2  hello
C  3  hello

cat world.txt
D  4  world
E  5  world
F  6  world
```

EDIT:
I should have included some previous attempts for this as mentioned below. I know how one could do this if the patterns were known ahead of time using something like grep, but am not sure how to allow it to accept wildcards. This is what I normally do if I know I will only need to extract by a very specific pattern.

```
echo "$foo" | grep -w "hello" > hello.txt
echo "$foo" | grep -w "world" > world.txt
```

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far, however inadequate, and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was really quite stuck and couldn't think of any solutions to this, which is why I had no code to show. The only solutions I could come up with required that the pattern be known beforehand, but will post an example as an edit.

Comment: Excellent update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
   awk '{print > $3 ".txt"}' <<< "$foo"
```

Ex.

```
$ echo "$foo"
A  1  hello
B  2  hello
C  3  hello
D  4  world
E  5  world
F  6  world

awk '{print > $3 ".txt"}' <<< "$foo"

$ head {hello,world}.txt
==> hello.txt <==
A  1  hello
B  2  hello
C  3  hello

==> world.txt <==
D  4  world
E  5  world
F  6  world
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense and works perfectly.